# Java 8 Applying stream filter based on a condition

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In Java 8, is there a way to apply the filter on a stream based on a condition,

example

I have this stream

```
if (isAccessDisplayEnabled) {
     src = (List < Source > ) sourceMeta.getAllSources.parallelStream()
         .filter(k - > isAccessDisplayEnabled((Source) k))
         .filter(k - > containsAll((Source) k, substrings, searchString))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
 } else {
     src = (List < Source > ) sourceMeta.getAllSources.parallelStream()
         .filter(k - > containsAll((Source) k, substrings, searchString))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
 }
```

I am adding the filter

```
.filter(k - > isAccessDisplayEnabled((Source) k)))
```

on the stream based on the if-else condition. Is there a way to avoid that if-else, since if there are more filters coming up,then it will be hard to maintain.

Please let me know

Answer (score 52, accepted):

One way to do it is

```
Stream<Source> stream = sourceMeta.getAllSources.parallelStream().map(x -> (Source)x);
if(isAccessDisplayEnabled) stream = stream.filter(s -> isAccessDisplayEnabled(s));
src = stream.filter(s - > containsAll(s, substrings, searchString))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

another

```
 src = sourceMeta.getAllSources.parallelStream().map(x -> (Source)x)
     .filter(isAccessDisplayEnabled? s - > isAccessDisplayEnabled(s): s -> true)
     .filter(s - > containsAll(s, substrings, searchString))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In either case, note how performing one type cast at the beginning simplifies the entire stream pipline.

Both solutions avoid re-evaluating `isAccessDisplayEnabled` for every stream element, however, the second relies on the JVM’s capability of inlining `s -> true` when this code turns out to be performance critical.

Comment: I am not able to understand this line, isAccessDisplayEnabled? s -> true: s - > isAccessDisplayEnabled(s), please can you explain a bit more or to a blog that explains it.

Comment: Try reading it as `isAccessDisplayEnabled? (s -> true): (s -> isAccessDisplayEnabled(s))`. If `isAccessDisplayEnabled` is `true`, use the lambda expression `s -> true`, which is effectively like having no filter, otherwise, use `s - > isAccessDisplayEnabled(s)`. It’s a combination of the [ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) with two alternative [lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: @Holder : ok for ternary but order is wrong , no ? I guess if you have a boolean isAccessDisplayEnabled then you want to filter, otherwise if false  you do not filter. 
` isAccessDisplayEnabled? (s -> isAccessDisplayEnabled(s)) :  (s -> true) `

Comment: Why not to use `filter(!isAccessDisplayEnabled || isAccessDisplayEnabled(s))` ?

Comment: @Cherry the syntax would be `filter(s -> !isAccessDisplayEnabled || isAccessDisplayEnabled(s))` and it would work, but as said in the answer, *both solutions [of the answer] avoid re-evaluating `isAccessDisplayEnabled` for every stream element*. Since `isAccessDisplayEnabled` doesn’t change throughout the entire operation, it would be a waste of CPU cycles to check this over and over again.

Comment: i like all of this approaches :)

Comment: Your second solution with the ternary operator just solved a problem that stumped me for the last hour. I didn't even think to use it in a lambda. Thanks.

Comment: @umar it bascially uses the ternary operator :) ( see https://www.baeldung.com/java-ternary-operator for a tutorial about that)

Answer (score 5):

Your condition has the same name as your method. I'm going to assume you meant for those to be different, so let's say it was this:

```
if (someCondition) {
    src = (List < Source > ) sourceMeta.getAllSources.parallelStream()
        .filter(k - > isAccessDisplayEnabled((Source) k))
        .filter(k - > containsAll((Source) k, substrings, searchString))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
} else {
    src = (List < Source > ) sourceMeta.getAllSources.parallelStream()
        .filter(k - > containsAll((Source) k, substrings, searchString))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If you want to remove the if/else, you can instead perform the check in the first filter:

```
src = (List < Source > ) sourceMeta.getAllSources.parallelStream()
    .filter(k - > !someCondition || isAccessDisplayEnabled((Source) k))
    .filter(k - > containsAll((Source) k, substrings, searchString))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In the else case, you take everything and remove the isAccessDisplayEnabled() method call, so the condition is effectively "if someCondition is false or isAccessDisplayEnabled(k)". If someCondition comes out false, then the isAccessDisplayEnabled() check is skipped.

Comment: …but `someCondition` may get reevaluated for every element.

Comment: A variable and a method can have the same name in Java. Java is a Lisp 2 in that sense. ;)

Comment: @DavidConrad I'm sure that's true, however I don't think he meant it that way. I just changed the variable name to clear things up.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, i miss typed variable and method have different names